# Ansible Tower - copy file

Tags: ansible, yaml, credentials, ansible-tower

I am using ansible tower to copy a file from MachineA to MachineB and I have an issue:

My playbook is as follow:

```
- name: copy file from A to B
  synchronize:
    src: /tmp/file.txt
    dest: /tmp_folder/
    mode: push
  delegate_to: machineA
```

The problem is that MachineA and MachineB have differents credentials, so the playbook cannot copy the file from the MachineA to MachineB

I have been trying to configure two differents credentials in Tower, but is not allowed.

Any ideas???

Thank You!
Best regards

Comment: You have to set those different credentials for each relevant host in your inventory. Ideally, you should set some sort of deploy user on each of your managed servers and use the same ssh key to connect to them.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I don't know how to set differents credentials for Tower, with variables, maybe? Could you please share any web with the steps. I have been googling and have not found how to put two different credentials in Tower's inventory

Comment: In bulk (but with some sort of relevant order....): https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#connection-variables - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/credentials.html#vault

Answer (score 0):

1.If Machine A is your ansible master and tower

- Above synchronize model won't be work. Because you are using the user name and password to connect Machine B.
- If you use the Master **SSH key** to connect the Machine B, synchronize module will be work.

2. If Machine A and Machine B are the two ansible node

- Synchronize module only rsync the files from Ansible Master to nodes.
- Not between the two different ansible node.
  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/synchronize_module.html
- If you want to achieve the copy the files from two ansible node(Machine A to Machine B), first copy the files from Machine A to Ansible Master using **Copy Module** and sync the copied files from Master to Machine B using **synchronize module**

Thank you.